# Center Nav Bar inside Svg

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/ikey2244/pen/NAObkK

```
 <header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="site-nav">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

css

```
svg
  width: 100%
  height: auto


.site-nav 
  display: flex

li
  margin: 40px
  list-style: none
  font-size: 30px
  font-family: 'Amatica SC', cursive
  font-weight: bold
  display: block

a
  text-decoration: none
  color: #652A83
```

What would be the best way to make the navigation bar right center inside the svg? I also want to make the navigation bar responsive to where it scales with the svg.

Comment: You should use just the left side of that svg (cut it from left side) and make it fixed height (like 90px) then make the nav also 90px height and set the nav background to match svg background color..

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean?